# Django Identifying Class Based View and Form Multiple Models

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I'm on my second Django project. On my first project I used all generic views, with only the most basic forms tied directly to a custom user model using `UpdateView`.

In this project I'm trying to implement user profile functionality. My custom user model has some extra dummy fields just so I can manipulate the data. This I refer so as the `CustomUser` model. I also have a `UserAddress` model containing addresses since a user can have more than one address. I have tried looking for other questions, and I get similar questions, but there is always something missing:

[Django class based views - UpdateView with two model forms - one submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18122096/django-class-based-views-updateview-with-two-model-forms-one-submit)

[Using Multiple ModelForms with Class-Based Views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16422529/using-multiple-modelforms-with-class-based-views)

[Multiple Models in a single django ModelForm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770810/multiple-models-in-a-single-django-modelform)

[Django: multiple models in one template using forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569468/django-multiple-models-in-one-template-using-forms)

I've spent the last day or two looking for the "Django way" of doing what I want to do and have had no luck. My initial thought was that I could use a single template, fed with two ModelForms wrapped in a single `<form>` tag. The view would then process each form and update the `CustomUser` model and create or update the `UserAddress` models. I have figured out how to mash together the functionality using the base `View` CBV, but I suspect I'm duplicating a lot of functionality that I could probably find already done in Django. This is my view, where I handle the form instantiating manually, and feed the `context`.

```
class UserDetailsView(View):

    def get(self, request):
        user = request.user
        user_basic = CustomUser.objects.get(pk=user.pk)
        basic_form = UserBasicForm(instance=user_basic)

        user_address = UserAddress.objects.get(user=user.pk)   
        billing_address_form = UserAddressForm(instance = user_address)

        context = {'basic_form':basic_form,'billing_address_form':billing_address_form}

        return render(request, 'mainapp/profile.html', context)
```

My `post` is the same at this point, as I haven't done the actual validation and saving yet.

```
class UserBasicForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta(forms.ModelForm):
        model = CustomUser
        fields = (
            'username',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            )
        labels = {
            'username':'Username',
            'first_name':'First Name',
            'last_name':'Last Name',
            }

class UserAddressForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta(forms.ModelForm):
        model = UserAddress
        fields = (
            'description',
            'addressee',
            'company',
            'address_1',
            'address_2',
            'city',
            'prov_state',
            'post_zip',
            'country',
            )
        labels = {
            'description':'Address Description',
            'addressee':'Addressee',
            'company':'Company Name',
            'address_1':'Address',
            'address_2':'Address 2',
            'city':'City',
            'prov_state':'Province or State',
            'post_zip':'Postal or Zip Code',
            'country':'Country',
            }

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

class UserAddress(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)

    description = models.CharField(max_length = 256, default='Description')

    addressee = models.CharField(max_length = 256,)
    company = models.CharField(max_length = 256, default='Self')
    address_1 = models.CharField(max_length = 256,)
    address_2 = models.CharField(max_length = 256,)
    city = models.CharField(max_length = 256,)
    prov_state = models.CharField(max_length = 256,)
    post_zip = models.CharField(max_length = 256,)
    country = models.CharField(max_length = 256,)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description
```

Please go easy on me, I'll take most advice offered.

**Edit**
After reviewing some other SO questions and Django form examples, it appears that the final answer probably isn't SO material. That said, my observation is that for the Django built-in CBVs, the "best" base view is that which you can minimize or simplify the code you add. Using a TemplateView or FormView for my project in this case just depends on which methods I choose to re-write or override and for that, I'm still open to suggestions.

Comment: did you try to just extend the basic form from the address form class?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I understand what you mean. A ModelForm and associated methods should work well as the data is tightly coupled to the model (I think). Am I misinterpreting?

Comment: The view logic is what I feel should likely exist built into Django...the forms and templates I think are project dependent.

Comment: Yeah should. Try this: https://django-betterforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/multiform.html#working-with-modelforms

Comment: I see...I saw another SO answer where they used composite forms, but I couldn't figure out how to make a view work with that. At the time, I felt like a bit of duct tape solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something like this ([with betterforms](https://django-betterforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/multiform.html#working-with-modelforms)):

```
class UserCreationMultiForm(MultiModelForm):
    form_classes = {
        'basic': UserBasicForm,
        'address': UserAddressForm,
    }


class UserDetailsView(View):
    template = "mainapp/profile.html"
    form_class = UserCreationMultiForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # Save the user first, because the profile needs a user before it
        # can be saved.
        user = form['basic'].save()
        address = form['address'].save(commit=False)
        address.user = user
        address.save()
        return redirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Then rename your forms in your template to `form.basic` and `form.address`

Comment: So this would use the generic `View` because it contains data from multiple models?

Comment: After reviewing many more SO questions and answers, I realized I was making a few stupid mistakes that didn't make things any easier. My initial idea to use Django built in views matches other solutions where a main model and form is used in `UpdateView`, and other data is managed manually.

For now, I'm looking to avoid multi-form solutions, to keep dependencies down. Your approach uses the generic `view` which is pretty much what I was doing on my previous project.

I'll leave this open for now for further input.